# altair: boxplot with one observation

Tags: python, altair

I am working on a dashboard for a project where I am receiving updated data on a daily basis (meaning that some of the dataframes are only poorly populated).

I would like to visualize the different groups via boxplots, but I noticed that during the beginning of the project, sometimes the underlying dataframes only contain one entry.

Here is my question: If I am visualizing a boxplot with only one data point, it does not show anything (see code and screenshots below). Is it possible to show a single point for only one observation such as outliers are shown? Thank you very much

Code:

```py
import pandas as pd
import altair as alt

df1 = pd.DataFrame({"a": [1,3,2,5,4,5,3,6,4,3,5,10]})
alt.Chart(df1).mark_boxplot().encode(
    alt.X("a")
)
```

[image: df1]

```py
df2 = pd.DataFrame({"b": [1]})
alt.Chart(df2).mark_boxplot().encode(
    alt.X("b")
)
```

[image: df2]

Comment: This issue is reported in https://github.com/vega/vega-lite/issues/8338 and the other issue linked there. There is a also an open PR draft linked there, and feel free to weigh in as well.

Comment: Thank you for bringing that to my attention.